# Should barcode font sizes match?

Tags: asp.net, barcode

I am trying to convert a string into Code39 barcode. To increase the reliability I am trying to increase the font size of barcode from 40 to 60. Would this cause any issue as the width and height of the bars will change compared to the previous version of font 40?

Comment: AFAIK, bar-code scanners are pretty darn flexible, at least, the laser-based ones. The people who make the Code39 font list uses of the font from sizes 6 to 48, but they don't say anything about going larger than that (http://www.idautomation.com/fonts/free/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the scanner reads the ratio between the width of the symbols.  As long as they both scale the same way, you're fine.  I doubt that you'll see increased reliability.  I hope you'll post results.

Comment: I have increased the font size and is working great. Increase in font size helped maintain the quality of the barcode over multiple photocopies and faxes. Thank You.